# Problem with modal when page starts and button disappears

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a new Pop Up-style ad for the site here of the company that I'm working on. But I'm in a different situation where I need instead of running the modal JUST when checked box, but that it always run when the page starts, I've tried too many ways, not successfully, because when I can get it to just show up (which is my goal), the close button no longer works.

I'm sending my code in ATTACHMENT, it's pretty clean, and it's only 25 lines, could you please explain this to me?
Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TESTE MODAL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheets/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <!--
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
      $("#modal_chaves").modal("show");
      });
      </script>
  -->
      <label id="" class="" for="modal_chaves">Clique aqui</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="modal_chaves" />
      <div id="modal_chaves" class="modal">
        <div id="modal_chaves" class="modal-content">
          <img src="assets/images/chaves-fotos-raras-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <label class="modal-close" for="modal_chaves"></label>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
label{
  margin:0; padding:0; border:0; background:transparent;
  /*vertical-align: baseline;*/
}

/* init modal */
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 999s 999s inherit;
  transition: all 999s 999s inherit;
}
.modal-content {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 360px;
  max-height: 85%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 999s inherit;
  transition: all 999s inherit;
}
.modal-content img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
.modal-content p {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.modal-close:after {
  content: "X";
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}

input[id*="modal_"] {
  position: fixed;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}
input[id*="modal_"]:checked + div.modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
input[id*="modal_"]:checked + div.modal .modal-content {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal-content {
    padding: 10px 5%;
    min-width: 88%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap with the website?

Comment: You seem to be missing a lot of necessary details in your code examples. You're clearly using JQuery, but it is not included in your example as a javascript source. Jquery does not ship with a `modal` plugin, so you must use a plugin for that. Please edit your question and let answerers know what JQuery plugin you are using to provide your modal functionality.